# Nginx service on Docker giving better performance on 1GB RAM Node than 4GB RAM Node

Tags: nginx, docker, cloud, system

I have 1 Master node and 2 Worker Nodes.
Worker1 - 1GB RAM, 1vCore
Worker2 - 4Gb RAM, 2vCore
I have a new 6 Nginx services running on different ports on both the Nodes.
When I do an Apache Benchmark test, it shows the performance (Requests per second) of the Worker1's services  is slightly better than Worker2's.
I do not understand why is it giving a better performance.

Other Details-I downloaded the latest image on nginx, assigned port values and started performing the test on nginx welcome page.

Comment: And what is the question? Maybe there are other factors... network path, network cards, network speed, who knows.